# Searching an Access Table for information based on another query in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Smart People of the internet.. I could really use your help !!
Complete novice here so I hope my question is not too confusing :/

I'm working with an access mdb file and reading some data from various tables using visual basic.

Here's my scenario:

**Table 1** in Access contains an ID (first column) followed by several True/False columns (Label A, Label B, Label C, etc..) 
so for example:

```
ID, Label A, Label B, Label C, Label D,
1, Y,Y,N,N
2, Y,N,N,N
3, Y,N,Y,Y
```

**Table 2** in Access looks like this (2 columns) - the value in column 2 is the same as the column name for the true/false column in table 1..

```
Item, LabelReq
1 , Label A
1 , Label B
2, Label A
3, Label A
3, Label C
3. Label D
```

I can't figure out how to use the output from my first query (that reads table 2) and gets a list of "Labels" per selection and use it to see if that Label is "True/False" in Table 1.

If the first query would have returned one value only I think I could do it but how would I deal with an unknown number of replies from the first query?

So If  my first query returns

```
"Label A"
"Label B"
"Label C"
```

How would I check that against Table 1 (to get that True/False) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show what you want your final (sample) output to look like for this example?

Comment: Example: User ID  1  inputs "Item" 1, then system searches table 2 and finds item "1" requires "Label A" and "Label 2".... Then the system searches Table 1 and returns if User ID "1" has "Label 1" and "Label 2"  are true.. (this example was just for 2 labels .. but I need that for any number of labels. )

So ideally User ID "1" enter Item "1" and gets back "True" or "False"